# How do I add a plaintext file in a second column in a makeshift hexdump program?

Tags: c, hexdump

I'm attempting to recreate a hexdump program in C. This is what I have so far

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef unsigned char byte;
void openfile(FILE **fptr, char *fname)
{
    *fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
    if(fptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "How dare you... \n");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
int readContents(FILE *fptr, int *filesize, byte *array)
{
        return (fread(array, 1, *filesize, fptr));  // read all bytes from the file
}

int printit(FILE **fptr, int *filesize, byte *array)
{
    byte sixteen[17];

    readContents(*fptr, filesize, array);

    int idx;
    for(idx = 0; idx <= *filesize; idx++)
    {
        if((idx%16)==0)
        {       
            printf("%08x ", idx);
        }

        if((idx%8)==0)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        printf("%02x ", array[idx]);

        if((idx+1)%16==0) 
        {
        printf("\n");
        }
    }

    for(idx = 0; idx <= *filesize; idx++)
    {
        if((idx%16)==0)
        printf("%c ", array[idx]);
    }


}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char filename[30];

    if(argc > 1)
    {
        strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a filename: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", filename);
    }

    FILE *ptr;
    openfile(&ptr, filename);

    fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    int filelen = ftell(ptr);
    printf("Length of file is: %d\n", filelen);
    fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);

    byte *bytes = malloc(filelen);


    printit(&ptr, &filelen, bytes);

    printf("\n");
    free(bytes);
    fclose(ptr);
}
```

The offset placement and hexes appear successfully in the output, but I just can't seem to figure out how I should add a column on the right hand side with the plaintext of the contents of a file

This is what the output looks like without it

```
00000010  03 00 3e 00 01 00 00 00  70 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000020  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  98 2b 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000030  00 00 00 00 40 00 38 00  09 00 40 00 1d 00 1c 00 
00000040  06 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000050  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000060  f8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  f8 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000070  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
00000080  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000090  38 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000a0  1c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000b0  01 00 00 00 05 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000d0  38 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00  38 0f 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000000e0  00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 00 06 00 00 00 
000000f0  50 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00  50 1d 20 00 00 00 00 00 
00000100  50 1d 20 00 00 00 00 00  c0 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000110  e0 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 
00000120  02 00 00 00 06 00 00 00  60 1d 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000130  60 1d 20 00 00 00 00 00  60 1d 20 00 00 00 00 00 
00000140  f0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  f0 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000150  08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 
00000160  54 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  54 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000170  54 02 00 00 00 00 00 00  44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000180  44 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00000190  50 e5 74 64 04 00 00 00  f0 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000001a0  f0 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00  f0 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000001b0  3c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  3c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
000001c0  04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  51 e5 74 64 06 00 00 00 
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

And this is where the plaintext appears at the end

```
  @   @ � 8 8    8  P P �  ` � T T D P � <     R P �  d o G  G `      J   o   +   D   u   �      
                                                                                                                                                   �   h . e n a c o s i i i L . I C n e b      u P p  �   �       p   �   �   �   �   �   �   � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � 1 � � H 9 � ] H ) H � ] �  � � U � � � � 5 � � H � U  � � � � � � H ,  � � � � H � �  � �  � d � A   � � L  A �  n : D . V   x   f F d f  � X �       � 
                                                                                                                                            �  �  � A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    p  
     �                                                                         

              � � � � �      `  � � � �  6 V    G . 4   8   t   �   �   0   X   `      �   P   `         �   0 7  X m  P �   �   �  ` �  � �      K   g   �   �   �   �      '    C e 0 � +  f  z w   �   �   �  X  f m o o d a n  n e A _ M _ F L _ p . a . e r 5 @ t L G b L a @ l _ _ s c @ b o 5 @ @ T e b I f 2 I a r t . n . s n e l n r m f m c      8    T    t    �    �    �    �    �    0   B    X    p    `   p             �    0    P   X   `    P          0     @    x    �
```

I also happen to be reading an ELF file, FYI

EDIT: I forgot to paste #include stdio.h

Comment: the posted code does not compile!  The code is using functions like: `printf()` and `fopen()` and `fclose()` and `fread()` and defined items like `FILE*` and `NULL`.  To use those items, the code needs the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: the function: `fread()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int` and the function: `printit()` is ignoring the returned value from the function: `readContents()`  Why is the function: `printit()` being passed a `FILE **` when it does not modify that pointer?

Comment: You output 16-hex values, when you finish outputting the last hex value, then print an optional separator, e.g. `" | "` and then loop over each of those 16-bytes outputting the printable value `if (isprint())` otherwise output a `' '`, then print the `'\n'` for that line of output.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: I agree with @DavidC.Rankin, with one minor modification. `dump` traditionally prints `.` for characters that aren't printable (though it's still ambiguous, so this is "better" only in being what people expect).

Comment: @user3629249 where exactly should I add ```if((idx+1)%16==0)```?

Comment: add the printing of the characters from the 'plain text' file before outputting a newline.

Comment: regarding: `for(idx = 0; idx <= *filesize; idx++)
    {
        if((idx%16)==0)
        printf("%c ", array[idx]);
    }`  This will only output a single character.  Note the `<=` will perform one too many loops.  suggest: `<`.   Suggest:  `for(idx = 0; idx % 16; idx++)
    {
        if( isprint( array[idx] )
             {   printf("%c ", array[idx]);  }  else { printf( "%c ", '.' ); }
    }`

Comment: I don't know what it means to "loop over those 16 bytes" I don't know what that looks like. Once I print the hex values, I am to loop over those printed 16 bytes and then print the plain text of that output. But what does that look like?

Comment: Note:  in C, the valid array indexes are 0...(number of elements in array -1 )

Comment: Note: an `ELF` file is NOT a plain text file

Comment: regarding the error message: `fprintf(stderr, "How dare you... \n");`  When the error is from a C library function, should output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  Suggest: `perror( "How dare you..." );` as that handles both actions.  Also, "How dare you..." tells the user nothing useful.  Suggest: `perror( "fopen failed" );`

Comment: suggest, since the code is only working with 16 bytes of the input file at a time, to use something like:  `fread( array, 1, 16, fptr);`  and pay attention to the returned value, as the chances of the input file being exactly a multiple of 16 bytes is quite small

Comment: regarding: `scanf(" %[^\n]s", filename);`  a 'character set' is complete unto it self, so the trailing `s` is expected to be the next char in `stdin`.  However, the next char will be `'\n'`  So this call to `scanf()` will fail.  Suggest: `if( scanf( "%29[^\n], filename ) != 1 ) { // handle error and exit }`

Comment: regarding: `if(argc > 1)
    {
        strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
    }`  If the file name entered by the user is greater than 29 characters, then a buffer overflow will occur.  This result in undefined behavior. Similar considerations exist for: `else
    {
        printf("Please enter a filename: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", filename);
    }`

Comment: If fread only uses 16 bytes, only the first 16 bytes will print. I don't know how to loop those 16 bytes so they all show up

Comment: I added an example that shows one way to approach handling the file in 16-byte chunks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. checks for and handles any errors
3. produces the desired output
4. avoids the use of `malloc()` and `free()`
5. does not try to consume the whole input file in one gulp

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>


#define MAX_BYTES 16
#define MAX_FILENAME_LEN 30

typedef unsigned char byte;

static unsigned int idx = 0;

void printit( size_t bytesRead, byte *array)
{
    // display index into file
    printf("\n%08x ", idx);

    for( size_t i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++  )
    {
        if( i == 8 )
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        printf("%02x ", array[i]);
    }

    printf( "%s", " | " );

    for( size_t i = 0; i< bytesRead; i++ )
    {
        if( isalpha( array[i] ) )
        {
             printf( "%c", array[i] );
        }

        else
        {
             printf( "%c", '.' );
        }
    }
    printf( "%s", " | " );

    idx += (unsigned int)bytesRead;  
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char filename[ MAX_FILENAME_LEN ];

    if(argc > 1)
    {
        strncpy(filename, argv[1], MAX_FILENAME_LEN );
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a filename: ");
        if( scanf("%29s", filename) != 1 )
        {
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf to get filename from user failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if( ! fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen for input file failed");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_END );
    long filelen = ftell( fp );
    printf("Length of file is: %ld\n", filelen);
    fseek( fp, 0, SEEK_SET );

    byte filedata[ 16 ];
    size_t bytesRead;
    while( ( bytesRead = fread( filedata, 1, sizeof filedata, fp )) > 0 )
    {
        //printf( "bytesRead: %zu\n", bytesRead );
        printit( bytesRead, filedata );
    }

    fclose( fp );
}
```

here is a typical run of the proposed code, against the source file:

```
Please enter a filename: untitled2.c
Length of file is: 1533

00000000 09 23 69 6e 63 6c 75 64  65 20 3c 73 74 72 69 6e  | ..include..strin | 
00000010 67 2e 68 3e 0a 09 23 69  6e 63 6c 75 64 65 20 3c  | g.h....include.. | 
00000020 73 74 64 6c 69 62 2e 68  3e 0a 09 23 69 6e 63 6c  | stdlib.h....incl | 
00000030 75 64 65 20 3c 73 74 64  69 6f 2e 68 3e 0a 09 23  | ude..stdio.h.... | 
00000040 69 6e 63 6c 75 64 65 20  3c 63 74 79 70 65 2e 68  | include..ctype.h | 
00000050 3e 0a 0a 0a 09 23 64 65  66 69 6e 65 20 4d 41 58  | ......define.MAX | 
00000060 5f 42 59 54 45 53 20 31  36 0a 09 23 64 65 66 69  | .BYTES......defi | 
00000070 6e 65 20 4d 41 58 5f 46  49 4c 45 4e 41 4d 45 5f  | ne.MAX.FILENAME. | 
00000080 4c 45 4e 20 33 30 0a 0a  09 74 79 70 65 64 65 66  | LEN......typedef | 
00000090 20 75 6e 73 69 67 6e 65  64 20 63 68 61 72 20 62  | .unsigned.char.b | 
000000a0 79 74 65 3b 0a 0a 09 73  74 61 74 69 63 20 75 6e  | yte....static.un | 
000000b0 73 69 67 6e 65 64 20 69  6e 74 20 69 64 78 20 3d  | signed.int.idx.. | 
000000c0 20 30 3b 0a 0a 09 76 6f  69 64 20 70 72 69 6e 74  | ......void.print | 
000000d0 69 74 28 20 73 69 7a 65  5f 74 20 62 79 74 65 73  | it..size.t.bytes | 
000000e0 52 65 61 64 2c 20 62 79  74 65 20 2a 61 72 72 61  | Read..byte..arra | 
000000f0 79 29 0a 09 7b 0a 09 09  2f 2f 20 64 69 73 70 6c  | y..........displ | 
00000100 61 79 20 69 6e 64 65 78  20 69 6e 74 6f 20 66 69  | ay.index.into.fi | 
00000110 6c 65 0a 09 09 70 72 69  6e 74 66 28 22 5c 6e 25  | le...printf...n. | 
00000120 30 38 78 20 22 2c 20 69  64 78 29 3b 0a 09 09 0a  | ..x....idx...... | 
00000130 09 09 66 6f 72 28 20 73  69 7a 65 5f 74 20 69 20  | ..for..size.t.i. | 
00000140 3d 20 30 3b 20 69 20 3c  20 62 79 74 65 73 52 65  | .....i...bytesRe | 
00000150 61 64 3b 20 69 2b 2b 20  20 29 0a 09 09 7b 0a 09  | ad..i........... | 
00000160 09 09 69 66 28 20 69 20  3d 3d 20 38 20 29 0a 09  | ..if..i......... | 
00000170 09 09 7b 0a 09 09 09 09  70 72 69 6e 74 66 28 22  | ........printf.. | 
00000180 20 22 29 3b 0a 09 09 09  7d 0a 0a 09 09 09 70 72  | ..............pr | 
00000190 69 6e 74 66 28 22 25 30  32 78 20 22 2c 20 61 72  | intf.....x....ar | 
000001a0 72 61 79 5b 69 5d 29 3b  0a 09 09 7d 0a 09 09 0a  | ray.i........... | 
000001b0 09 09 70 72 69 6e 74 66  28 20 22 25 73 22 2c 20  | ..printf....s... | 
000001c0 22 20 7c 20 22 20 29 3b  0a 09 09 0a 09 09 66 6f  | ..............fo | 
000001d0 72 28 20 73 69 7a 65 5f  74 20 69 20 3d 20 30 3b  | r..size.t.i..... | 
000001e0 20 69 3c 20 62 79 74 65  73 52 65 61 64 3b 20 69  | .i..bytesRead..i | 
000001f0 2b 2b 20 29 0a 09 09 7b  0a 09 09 09 69 66 28 20  | ............if.. | 
00000200 69 73 61 6c 70 68 61 28  20 61 72 72 61 79 5b 69  | isalpha..array.i | 
00000210 5d 20 29 20 29 0a 09 09  09 7b 0a 09 09 09 09 20  | ................ | 
00000220 70 72 69 6e 74 66 28 20  22 25 63 22 2c 20 61 72  | printf....c...ar | 
00000230 72 61 79 5b 69 5d 20 29  3b 0a 09 09 09 7d 0a 09  | ray.i........... | 
00000240 09 09 20 0a 09 09 09 65  6c 73 65 0a 09 09 09 7b  | .......else..... | 
00000250 0a 09 09 09 09 20 70 72  69 6e 74 66 28 20 22 25  | ......printf.... | 
00000260 63 22 2c 20 27 2e 27 20  29 3b 0a 09 09 09 7d 0a  | c............... | 
00000270 09 09 7d 0a 09 09 70 72  69 6e 74 66 28 20 22 25  | ......printf.... | 
00000280 73 22 2c 20 22 20 7c 20  22 20 29 3b 0a 09 09 0a  | s............... | 
00000290 09 09 69 64 78 20 2b 3d  20 28 75 6e 73 69 67 6e  | ..idx.....unsign | 
000002a0 65 64 20 69 6e 74 29 62  79 74 65 73 52 65 61 64  | ed.int.bytesRead | 
000002b0 3b 20 20 0a 09 7d 0a 0a  0a 09 69 6e 74 20 6d 61  | ..........int.ma | 
000002c0 69 6e 28 69 6e 74 20 61  72 67 63 2c 20 63 68 61  | in.int.argc..cha | 
000002d0 72 20 2a 61 72 67 76 5b  5d 29 0a 09 7b 0a 09 09  | r..argv......... | 
000002e0 63 68 61 72 20 66 69 6c  65 6e 61 6d 65 5b 20 4d  | char.filename..M | 
000002f0 41 58 5f 46 49 4c 45 4e  41 4d 45 5f 4c 45 4e 20  | AX.FILENAME.LEN. | 
00000300 5d 3b 0a 0a 09 09 69 66  28 61 72 67 63 20 3e 20  | ......if.argc... | 
00000310 31 29 0a 09 09 7b 0a 09  09 09 73 74 72 6e 63 70  | ..........strncp | 
00000320 79 28 66 69 6c 65 6e 61  6d 65 2c 20 61 72 67 76  | y.filename..argv | 
00000330 5b 31 5d 2c 20 4d 41 58  5f 46 49 4c 45 4e 41 4d  | .....MAX.FILENAM | 
00000340 45 5f 4c 45 4e 20 29 3b  0a 09 09 7d 0a 09 09 0a  | E.LEN........... | 
00000350 09 09 65 6c 73 65 0a 09  09 7b 0a 09 09 09 70 72  | ..else........pr | 
00000360 69 6e 74 66 28 22 50 6c  65 61 73 65 20 65 6e 74  | intf..Please.ent | 
00000370 65 72 20 61 20 66 69 6c  65 6e 61 6d 65 3a 20 22  | er.a.filename... | 
00000380 29 3b 0a 09 09 09 69 66  28 20 73 63 61 6e 66 28  | ......if..scanf. | 
00000390 22 25 32 39 73 22 2c 20  66 69 6c 65 6e 61 6d 65  | ....s...filename | 
000003a0 29 20 21 3d 20 31 20 29  0a 09 09 09 7b 0a 09 09  | ................ | 
000003b0 09 09 66 70 72 69 6e 74  66 28 20 73 74 64 65 72  | ..fprintf..stder | 
000003c0 72 2c 20 22 73 63 61 6e  66 20 74 6f 20 67 65 74  | r...scanf.to.get | 
000003d0 20 66 69 6c 65 6e 61 6d  65 20 66 72 6f 6d 20 75  | .filename.from.u | 
000003e0 73 65 72 20 66 61 69 6c  65 64 5c 6e 22 20 29 3b  | ser.failed.n.... | 
000003f0 0a 09 09 09 09 65 78 69  74 28 20 45 58 49 54 5f  | .....exit..EXIT. | 
00000400 46 41 49 4c 55 52 45 20  29 3b 0a 09 09 09 7d 0a  | FAILURE......... | 
00000410 09 09 7d 0a 0a 09 09 46  49 4c 45 20 2a 66 70 20  | .......FILE..fp. | 
00000420 3d 20 66 6f 70 65 6e 28  66 69 6c 65 6e 61 6d 65  | ..fopen.filename | 
00000430 2c 20 22 72 62 22 29 3b  0a 09 09 69 66 28 20 21  | ...rb......if... | 
00000440 20 66 70 20 29 0a 09 09  7b 0a 09 09 09 70 65 72  | .fp..........per | 
00000450 72 6f 72 28 20 22 66 6f  70 65 6e 20 66 6f 72 20  | ror...fopen.for. | 
00000460 69 6e 70 75 74 20 66 69  6c 65 20 66 61 69 6c 65  | input.file.faile | 
00000470 64 22 29 3b 0a 09 09 09  65 78 69 74 28 20 45 58  | d.......exit..EX | 
00000480 49 54 5f 46 41 49 4c 55  52 45 20 29 3b 0a 09 09  | IT.FAILURE...... | 
00000490 7d 0a 0a 09 09 66 73 65  65 6b 28 20 66 70 2c 20  | .....fseek..fp.. | 
000004a0 30 2c 20 53 45 45 4b 5f  45 4e 44 20 29 3b 0a 09  | ...SEEK.END..... | 
000004b0 09 6c 6f 6e 67 20 66 69  6c 65 6c 65 6e 20 3d 20  | .long.filelen... | 
000004c0 66 74 65 6c 6c 28 20 66  70 20 29 3b 0a 09 09 70  | ftell..fp......p | 
000004d0 72 69 6e 74 66 28 22 4c  65 6e 67 74 68 20 6f 66  | rintf..Length.of | 
000004e0 20 66 69 6c 65 20 69 73  3a 20 25 6c 64 5c 6e 22  | .file.is...ld.n. | 
000004f0 2c 20 66 69 6c 65 6c 65  6e 29 3b 0a 09 09 66 73  | ..filelen.....fs | 
00000500 65 65 6b 28 20 66 70 2c  20 30 2c 20 53 45 45 4b  | eek..fp.....SEEK | 
00000510 5f 53 45 54 20 29 3b 0a  09 09 0a 09 09 62 79 74  | .SET.........byt | 
00000520 65 20 66 69 6c 65 64 61  74 61 5b 20 31 36 20 5d  | e.filedata...... | 
00000530 3b 0a 09 09 73 69 7a 65  5f 74 20 62 79 74 65 73  | ....size.t.bytes | 
00000540 52 65 61 64 3b 0a 09 09  77 68 69 6c 65 28 20 28  | Read....while... | 
00000550 20 62 79 74 65 73 52 65  61 64 20 3d 20 66 72 65  | .bytesRead...fre | 
00000560 61 64 28 20 66 69 6c 65  64 61 74 61 2c 20 31 2c  | ad..filedata.... | 
00000570 20 73 69 7a 65 6f 66 20  66 69 6c 65 64 61 74 61  | .sizeof.filedata | 
00000580 2c 20 66 70 20 29 29 20  3e 20 30 20 29 0a 09 09  | ..fp............ | 
00000590 7b 0a 09 09 09 2f 2f 70  72 69 6e 74 66 28 20 22  | .......printf... | 
000005a0 62 79 74 65 73 52 65 61  64 3a 20 25 7a 75 5c 6e  | bytesRead...zu.n | 
000005b0 22 2c 20 62 79 74 65 73  52 65 61 64 20 29 3b 0a  | ...bytesRead.... | 
000005c0 09 09 09 70 72 69 6e 74  69 74 28 20 62 79 74 65  | ...printit..byte | 
000005d0 73 52 65 61 64 2c 20 66  69 6c 65 64 61 74 61 20  | sRead..filedata. | 
000005e0 29 3b 0a 09 09 7d 0a 09  09 0a 09 09 66 63 6c 6f  | ............fclo | 
000005f0 73 65 28 20 66 70 20 29  3b 0a 09 7d 0a  | se..fp....... |
```

Note: when the final read is less than 16 bytes, you might want to fill out the last line of the input with spaces

Note you might want to modify the `if( isalpha() )`  to `if( isprint() )` so other than the letters a..z and A..Z are printed

Comment: Change first loop in `printit()` to `for( size_t i = 0; i < MAX_BYTES; i++  )` to fix the last line output, but good job. Also `memset (filedata, 0, MAX_BYTES);` after you call `printit( bytesRead, filedata );` in `main()` to ensure the final bytes are zero when a short read occurs with the last line.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin,  I was trying to leave the OP with something to do that would require the OP to fully understand the answer so they could make the fix for the last line of the output

Comment: That's a good approach too -- a little intentional learning sprinkled in...

Answer (score 1):

I'd to the job somewhat differently. In fact, (many years ago) I did the job somewhat differently:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned long offset = 0;
    FILE *input;
    int bytes, i, j;
    unsigned char buffer[16];
    char outbuffer[60];

    if ( argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: dump filename [filename...]");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    for (j=1;j<argc; ++j) {

        if ( NULL ==(input=fopen(argv[j], "rb")))
            continue;

        printf("\n%s:\n", argv[j]);

        while (0 < (bytes=fread(buffer, 1, 16, input))) {
            sprintf(outbuffer, "%8.8lx: ", offset+=16);
            for (i=0;i<bytes;i++) {
                sprintf(outbuffer+10+3*i, "%2.2X ",buffer[i]);
                if (!isprint(buffer[i]))
                    buffer[i] = '.';
            }
            printf("%-60s %*.*s\n", outbuffer, bytes, bytes, buffer);
        }
        fclose(input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(**edited** to match `hexdump -Cv` output)

Along the same lines and continuing from my comment, if you read from your input file in 16-byte chunks, you can output the address and your hex-bytes and then add a separator and then loop separately again over the bytes to provide the ASCII values as the right column. Below the program takes the filename to read as the first argument (or it reads from `stdin` by default if no argument is given).

If the filename is provided, you can also provide a second option that provides the character to use in place of non-printing characters in the ASCII output (you should actually implement `getopt` to handle the arguments - but that if left to you should you desire).

A quick implementation could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define OFFSET 16   /* bytes to display per-line of output */

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buff[OFFSET] = "",
        sep = argc > 2 ? *argv[2] : '.';    /* default non-print char ','  */
    int bytes,                              /* (add getopt to handle opts) */
        address = 0,
        i;

    /* read from filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "rb") : stdin;
    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("fopen");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read OFFSET number of bytes at a time */
    while ((bytes = fread(buff, 1, sizeof buff, fp)) > 0) {
        /* print address */
        printf("%0*x  ", OFFSET / 2, address);
        address += OFFSET;

        /* print hex values */
        for (i = 0; i < OFFSET; i++) {
            if (i && i % (OFFSET / 2) == 0) /* additional space between bytes */
                putchar (' ');
            if (i >= bytes)                 /* final line where i >= bytes */
                fputs ("   ", stdout);
            else    /* output zero-padded hex-byte */
                printf("%02hhx ", (unsigned char)buff[i]);
        }
        fputs (" |", stdout);               /* add separator */

        /* print ascii values - putchar() outputs a single char */
        for (i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
            putchar (buff[i] >= ' ' && buff[i] <= '~' ? buff[i] : sep);
        puts ("|");     /* add closing '|' and \n */
    }
    printf("%0*x\n", OFFSET / 2, address);  /* output final address */

    if (fp != stdin)    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/hexdump dat/animals.bin.dat
00000000  01 00 41 62 69 67 61 69  6c 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |..Abigail.......|
00000010  74 01 00 00 74 01 43 61  70 72 69 63 6f 72 6e 69  |t...t.Capricorni|
00000020  73 20 73 75 6d 61 74 72  61 65 6e 73 69 73 00 00  |s sumatraensis..|
00000030  5c 3f 1b 00 5c 4f 1b 00  5c 53 08 00 02 00 75 6e  |\?..\O..\S....un|
00000040  6b 6e 6f 77 6e 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 74 01 00 00  |known.......t...|
...
00000370  73 00 73 69 73 00 00 00  5c 3f 1b 00 5c 4f 1b 00  |s.sis...\?..\O..|
00000380  5c 58 01 00                                       |\X..|
00000384
```

With a space provided as the second argument as the non-printing char for the ASCII output:

```
$ ./bin/hexdump dat/animals.bin.dat ' '
00000000  01 00 41 62 69 67 61 69  6c 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |  Abigail       |
00000010  74 01 00 00 74 01 43 61  70 72 69 63 6f 72 6e 69  |t   t Capricorni|
00000020  73 20 73 75 6d 61 74 72  61 65 6e 73 69 73 00 00  |s sumatraensis  |
00000030  5c 3f 1b 00 5c 4f 1b 00  5c 53 08 00 02 00 75 6e  |\?  \O  \S    un|
00000040  6b 6e 6f 77 6e 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 74 01 00 00  |known       t   |
...
00000370  73 00 73 69 73 00 00 00  5c 3f 1b 00 5c 4f 1b 00  |s sis   \?  \O  |
00000380  5c 58 01 00                                       |\X  |
00000384
```

Comparison with `hexdump -Cv`:

```
$ hexdump -Cv dat/animals.bin.dat
00000000  01 00 41 62 69 67 61 69  6c 00 00 00 04 00 00 00  |..Abigail.......|
00000010  74 01 00 00 74 01 43 61  70 72 69 63 6f 72 6e 69  |t...t.Capricorni|
00000020  73 20 73 75 6d 61 74 72  61 65 6e 73 69 73 00 00  |s sumatraensis..|
00000030  5c 3f 1b 00 5c 4f 1b 00  5c 53 08 00 02 00 75 6e  |\?..\O..\S....un|
00000040  6b 6e 6f 77 6e 00 00 00  04 00 00 00 74 01 00 00  |known.......t...|
...
00000370  73 00 73 69 73 00 00 00  5c 3f 1b 00 5c 4f 1b 00  |s.sis...\?..\O..|
00000380  5c 58 01 00                                       |\X..|
00000384
```

Let me know if you have further questions.